# Does the Tangent theorem for circumferences hold in the sphere $S^2$?

Tags: circles, curvature, spheres, tangent-line, geodesic

I am wondering if a kind of theorem of tangents from a point to a circumference holds in the sphere.

The situation that I have in mind is the following.
Take two geodesics $\gamma_1$ and $\gamma_2$ starting from a point $p\in S^2$ in direction $v_1$ and $v_2$ respectively ($\gamma_i$ parametrised by arc-lenght). follow the two geodesics for $\varepsilon$-time and find two points $x_1$ and $x_2$ whose distance from $p$ is $\varepsilon$. Now in $\gamma_i(\varepsilon)$ we have, considerated as vectors, the frame $\{\gamma_i(\varepsilon),\gamma_i'(\varepsilon), n_i\}$, where $n_i=\gamma_i(\varepsilon)\times\gamma_i'(\varepsilon)$.
Now, consider the two geodesics starting respectively from $x_1,x_2$ and directions $n_1,n_2$.

**Is it true that the two geodesics meet in a point C?**

**Is it true that** $\mathbf{d_{S^2}(x_1,C)=d_{S^2}(x_2,C)=r}$?

**How can we write the parameterization of the piece of circle starting to** $\mathbf{x_1}$**, ending in** $\mathbf{x_2}$, **with radius** $\mathbf{r}$ **and center** $\mathbf{C}$**?**

**Bonus:** What is the intrinsic curvature of this piece of circle?

Thank you in advance for your comments or responses.

Comment: From my calculus, the two geodesics do not meet at any point, which is obviously strange.

Comment: Any two geodesics on the sphere intersect.